# Can I set up dependency builds in Jenkins similar to TeamCity?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have not found information about that, I want to trigger build but before it executes, I want it to trigger some other pipelines and wait for a file created by these other pipelines to pass to a main Pipeline, can I do this in Jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, yes, in multiple ways depending on your actual use case.

The simplest way would be to create the job you want to call and then add a step for calling that job, copy artifacts from the job and then continue with the pipeline.
Using [Jenkins Build step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/):

```
stage ('Child job') {
  steps {
    build(job: 'foo', wait: true, propagate: true, parameters: [parameters_list])
  }
}
```

The parameter `wait` makes it so your pipeline waits for the child to complete run before continuing and `propagate` means that the result of the job is shown in the parent pipeline as well. The `parameters` section is needed only if your child job requires parameters. See the parameter types in the Build step documentation.

You can also use the [Jenkins pipeline snippet generator](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#snippet-generator) to create the call properly in your own Jenkins instance.

To get any build artifacts from the child job, the easiest way to go is to use the [Copy Artifact plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/copyartifact/). You'll need to `archiveArtifacts` in the first job and then

```
copyArtifacts fingerprintArtifacts: true, projectName: 'foo', selector: lastCompleted()
```

When the artifacts are needed.